# What is the value in being a download mirror or library host?

Tags: hosting

I've seen many companies host open source libraries like jQuery and Bootstrap or they provide download mirrors for open source software. I'm assuming these take a slight toll on the server load and cost money to maintain. What is the gain for the company hosting the resources?

I wasn't sure where to post this question, stack overflow didn't seem right, so I tried here. Let me know if it's better suited somewhere else.

Thanks in advance, 
Josh

Comment: You'd have to ask them. Some do it for the altruism, some do it for the good PR, some (like Google) are presumably doing it for the analytics data they can obtain with all those requests.

Comment: Is it possible to migrate the question, or should I delete it and put it on superuser?

Answer (score 1):

OK, first we need to clarify terminology. There is a very large difference between hosting mirrors of F/OSS software and a CDN. CDNs are services provided by companies like Cloudflare, Akamai, and AWS Cloudfront - they are able to deliver web application resources to users from their geographically-disperse points of presence, with the goal of being able to provide better performance due to being closer to the user than the actual web application server is. These CDNs are integral to the application, and using them requires modification of the software application.

Software mirrors, on the other hand, are much more simple. For a software mirror, some organization agrees to periodically sync their mirror site to a master site, and then their mirror site gets included in a list of possible download sites.

What do organizations gain from doing this? Well, a couple of possibilities come to mind:

- Favorable marketing and PR. When one sees that Company X hosts a software mirror for a package, that reflects positively on them and what they stand for
- Perhaps the organization itself is a heavy user of the software. In this case, they likely have a mirror anyway for internal use, and have chosen to make this resource available publicly

Comment: Ohhhh, good to know. Thanks for clarifying the difference!